# Links to specific answers break my ability to scroll on the page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, hyperlinks, permalink

I clicked an link to an answer today, my browser (win7, chrome 5) was scrolled all the way the bottom and would not scroll up.  When I tried, there was a "flicker" effect as each scroll up was immediately countered.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is with a stale javascript file.  Fix it by clearing your cache.

<sub>This was a *pre-emptive* question (I already knew the answer).  If I saw this glitch today, someone else might also.</sub>